# Why doesn't my PHP-generated javascript work?

Tags: php, javascript

i have the following javascript code

```
echo ' <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById("items").style.display="block";document.getElementById("fade").style.display="block""><span style="padding-left:0px"><input type="submit" name="r" style="width: 138px; font-weight:bold;  " value="Add item"/></span></a>
';
```

i am trying to execute the script from within a php script. when i click on the button to execute the java part of it, nothing happens. i then try it this way

```
echo ' <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('items').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"><span style="padding-left:0px"><input type="submit" name="r" style="width: 138px; font-weight:bold;  " value="Add item"/></span></a>
';
```

and got this parse error: parse error, expecting `'," or`';".

Comment: Share code. Get answers.

Comment: First, accept some answers. Second: PHP is executed server-side, javascript is executed client-side

Comment: You never answer back to those who help you, accept answers, plus you don't seem to try to understand the issues for yourself... guess you won't be getting much help around.

Comment: @Hamish Not true. Just look at the answers. Easy rep. :)

Comment: There's no need to downvote this question so harshly. It's clearly just a escaping issue but the OP using some confusing language to describe it. Give him a break :)

Comment: lol, FYI to all, i do accept some of the answers and to some i do response to. most of them i figured out after i posted the question. anyway thnx i will response to all even if they did no help me to solve my problem

Comment: The -1 should be for lack of looking at (or providing) the *produced* HTML and working off of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo ' <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('items').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"><span style="padding-left:0px"><input type="submit" name="r" style="width: 138px; font-weight:bold;  " value="Add item"/></span></a>
';
```

This will not work because the single quote params in the JS echo are breaking the PHP flow.  Try adding break characters before each single quotation in the echo, not sure what it is in PHP but try \'

IE:

```
Id('items')
```

becomes

```
Id(\'items\')
```

Comment: Ikke pointed me in the right direction already thanks i will consider this style thou

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape apostrophes in a string in php. Instead of

```
echo '(...) style.display='block' (...)';
```

do

```
echo '(...) style.display=\'block\' (...)';
```

That being said, try to split your code over multiple lines so it is at least somewhat readable. You can also write HTML in php like this:

```
<?php
// php code
echo 'php';
?>
<HTML code>
<?php
// more php code
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with PHP.

You are using `"` quotes to delimit JavaScript strings **inside** an HTML attribute values delimited using `"` characters.

As a result, the first `"` inside the JS terminates the HTML attribute value.

The quick hack is to use `&quot;` instead of `"` inside the attribute value.

The better solution is to use [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: i figured it out thanks to Ikke, and yes i am using it with php. i call it using php and then break part off for the client side

Comment: That you are generating the HTML and JS with PHP doesn't make the problem you are having something to do with PHP.